# Rake db:migrate mysql error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am new to ROR. I was just following the tutorials at [tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/index.htm). I have installed following gems:

```
abstract (1.0.0)  
actionmailer (3.0.3)  
actionpack (3.0.3)  
activemodel (3.0.3)  
activerecord (3.0.3)  
activerecord-mysql-adapter-flags (0.0.3)  
activerecord-ruby_mysql-adapter (0.1)  
activeresource (3.0.3)  
activesupport (3.0.3)  
arel (2.0.6)  
bigdecimal (1.1.0)  
builder (2.1.2)  
bundler (1.3.5)  
erubis (2.6.6)  
i18n (0.4.2)  
io-console (0.3)  
json (1.5.5)  
mail (2.2.14)  
mime-types (1.16)  
minitest (2.5.1)  
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)  
polyglot (0.3.1)  
rack (1.2.1)  
rack-mount (0.6.13)  
rack-test (0.5.6)  
rails (3.0.3)  
railties (3.0.3)  
rake (0.9.2.2)  
rdoc (3.9.5)   
thor (0.14.6)  
treetop (1.4.9)  
tzinfo (0.3.23)
```

When I tried to run `rake db:create` it gave me following warnings, but still created the databases.

```
F:\Rails Applications\Library>rake db:create
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/tas
k' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Library::Application#task called at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems
/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
```

and at the end of long output it said:

```
[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

But it has created the databases named library_development and library_testing in mysql.

Now when I run rake db:migrate it says the following:

```
 F:\Rails Applications\Library>rake db:migrate
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/tas
k' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
    at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Library::Application#task called at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems
/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: query: not connected: CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version`
varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

the gemfile looks like this

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql', '~>2.8.1'
gem 'activerecord-ruby_mysql-adapter', '~>0.1' 
gem 'rdoc'
# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Can anyone please help me???

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle exec rake db:create`? It might just be running the wrong version of rake.

Comment: Have you seen this http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-fix-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-use-rdoc-task-instead-1169.html

Comment: @bundacia no it gives same warning and error

Answer (score 2):

Rails 3.0.3 is fairly old.  The latest 3.x branch is at 3.2.18 or newer.  I suspect you might be using a newer gem with a version of Rails that's too old for it to function with.  If you post your Gemfile as a gist it should be easier to determine which gems could possibly be problematic.

Typically in such a case unbounded gems i.e. those without an explicit version set in the Gemfile will attempt to use a newer version of the Gem than the version of Rails can support and will break the app.

Update: The Gemfile you added only has a single unbounded gem: rdoc.  This gem seems to be using an older way of integrating tasks and so might be breaking with a newer version of rake.  We'll adjust both the versions of rake and the version of rdoc to match the time period that rails 3.0.3 came from.

The [version of rdoc](https://rubygems.org/gems/rdoc/versions) that was released closest to [rails 3.0.3](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions) is 3.0.1.  Change your Gemfile so instead of

```
gem 'rdoc'
```

it says

```
gem 'rdoc', '~> 3.0.1'
```

Next, run the following commands to install the [closest version of rake](https://rubygems.org/gems/rake/versions) to rails 3.0.3

```
gem uninstall rake --version 0.9.2.2
gem install rake --version 0.8.7
```

Now, run bundler to install the version of rdoc you've asked for:

```
bundle install
```

And finally use bundler to execute your rake command using the specific versions of the gems you've asked to use in the Gemfile:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If that doesn't solve it, you can always force using the specific version of rake you want to use like so:

```
bundle exec rake _0.8.7_ db:create
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but rake db:create is creating databases in mysql. I am posting the gemfile.

Comment: yeah,I solved it.I just replaced the libmysql.dll with older version in ruby/bin folder.thanks